# Where is the "Episodes" button on Pandora's Android app?

Tags: applications, pandora

In the ["Serial" podcast on Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/serial), welcome instructions are provided that tell people to press the Episodes button to be able to change episodes or seasons (e.g. to go back to Episode 1 when Pandora decides to start with Episode 2 for some strange reason).

I see the Episodes button when using the web app in a PC browser, but can't find it anywhere in the Android app (which does behave strangely in how it jumps around sometimes), though I still get the instructions to push the Episodes button.  Where is it in the Android app?